# Resize uploaded file before storage in database

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

We want to re-size the (Symfony) uploaded file. But we don't want to save the file on disk but still keep the file object and his properties. Before and after the resize. What is the best way for doing this ?

This the current code for the resize, but we want to keep the file object / or create new one for the information.

```
public function storeDocument(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file)
{
    switch ($file->getMimeType()){
        case 'image/gif':
            $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 50);
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedGifFile);

            imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 100, 100);
            break;
    }

    ob_start(); 
        imagepng($thumb);
        $pngImage = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean(); 

    //create file object ?

}
```

Comment: I have good experience with `SimpleImageClass`: https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage - Very easy to use, chained and intuitive.